# java two different classes stored in same object plus show in grid

Tags: java, class

I have two child classes, Chair and Table from a parent class called furnitureItem.

I need to be able to store either a Chair or a Table class into a grid like the below and be able to reference the class to that cell. I tried to used a collection but with no  and no sucess with an array of the parent class.

[Screenshot of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/123mW.png)

Chair class

```
public class Chair extends FurnitureItem {

private Boolean armRests;

Chair()
{
    super();
    armRests = false;
    itemPrice();
}
```

Table

```
public class Desk extends FurnitureItem {

private int width;
private int depth;
private int numOfDraws;

Desk()
{
    super();
    width = 0;
    depth = 0;
    numOfDraws = 0;
    itemPrice();
}
```